# issue with async await

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I am trying to make two block of code to run sequentially with async and await 
I have the code in stackblitz, open the console on Chrome to  see the trace

```
let isMomHappy = true;
function willIgotNewPhone () {
    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {

        if (isMomHappy) {
            const phone = {
                brand: 'samsung',
                color : 'black'
            };

            resolve(phone);
        } else {
            const reason = new Error('mom not happy');
            reject(reason);
        }
    });
}

async  function showOff(phone) {
    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
        const  message = ' Hey Friend I show  my phone ' + phone.brand;
        resolve(message);
    });
}


async function askMom() {
    return await new Promise( async (resolve) => {
        console.log('before asking Mom'); // log before
        await willIgotNewPhone()
            .then( function(fullfilled) {
                console.log('Got phone from mom ' + JSON.stringify(fullfilled));
            })
            .catch( function(error) {
                console.log(error.message);
            });
        console.log('after  asking Mom'); // afeter log
        resolve('END');
    });

}

let data: any[] = [];
async function createData() {
    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {

        for (let index = 0; index < 500000; index++) {
            const element: any = {};
            element.id = index;
            element.name = '' + index;
            data.push(element);
        }
        if (data && data.length > 0) {
            console.log('    ====== creating data size=%s', data.length);
            resolve(data);
        } else {
            reject( new Error('    ==== Creating data Error : empty'));
        }
    });
}


async function callCreateData() {
    return new Promise( async (resolve) => {
        console.log('    ======before creating data');
        await createData().then( (dataReturn: any[]) => {
            console.log('        ----datareturn length=%s', dataReturn.length);
        });
        console.log('    ======after creating data');
    });
}

async function callingMom() {
    await askMom().then( (str) => {
        console.log(str);
    });
}

callingMom();
callCreateData();
```

I am calling 2 functions     this.callingMom() and   this.callCreateData();
and expecting the traces of the 2 functions to be sequential

I was expecting the following output

```
before asking Mom
Got phone from mom {"brand":"samsung","color":"black"}
after  asking Mom
     =====before creating creating data
     ===== creating data size=500000
         ----datareturn length=500000
     ===== after creating creating data
```

but I got the output :

```
before asking Mom
    ======before creating data
    ====== creating data size=500000
Got phone from mom {"brand":"samsung","color":"black"}
        ----datareturn length=500000
    ======after creating data
after  asking Mom
END
```

Any idea what is my problem ?

Thanks

Comment: Unless you post the code you're using in your question, it's impossible to say what the problem is.

Comment: `make two block of code to run synchronously with async and await` ... think about this for a minute ... you want to use `async` to make a function run *synchronously* - `async` ensures that a function is ***a**synchronous*, the opposite of what you want  ... did you mean *sequentially*

Comment: @JaromandaX  Yes I mean sequentially

Comment: Well. That's completely possible then

Comment: Just update to add the link to code

Comment: @CertainPerformance  added the link to the code, the link didnt work initially when posting

Comment: Don't tell people who want to help to go to an external site - please read the How to Ask page. Post the code in the question. (Questions asking for help with code posted on an external site are off-topic and liable to be closed)

Comment: @CertainPerformance    just post the code here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`async` functions can be used for two things, primarilly: to return a `Promise`, and to be able to use the `await` keyword inside. If you're not using `await`, or if the only `await` you're using is the Promise that's going to be returned, there's no point in having an async function at all - just use a normal function that returns a Promise, like in your `willIgotNewPhone`.

Also, in order to chain promises together, you need to use `then`. Simply calling asynchronous functions right after the other won't cause the thread to pause until they're done. Like this:

```
callingMom().then(callCreateData);
```

```js
let isMomHappy = true;

function willIgotNewPhone() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    if (isMomHappy) {
      const phone = {
        brand: 'samsung',
        color: 'black'
      };

      resolve(phone);
    } else {
      const reason = new Error('mom not happy');
      reject(reason);
    }
  });
}

function showOff(phone) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const message = ' Hey Friend I show  my phone ' + phone.brand;
    resolve(message);
  });
}


function askMom() {
  return new Promise(async (resolve) => {
    console.log('before asking Mom'); // log before
    await willIgotNewPhone()
      .then(function(fullfilled) {
        console.log('Got phone from mom ' + JSON.stringify(fullfilled));
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error.message);
      });
    console.log('after  asking Mom'); // afeter log
    resolve('END');
  });

}

let data = [];
function createData() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    for (let index = 0; index < 500000; index++) {
      const element = {};
      element.id = index;
      element.name = '' + index;
      data.push(element);
    }
    if (data && data.length > 0) {
      console.log('    ====== creating data size=%s', data.length);
      resolve(data);
    } else {
      reject(new Error('    ==== Creating data Error : empty'));
    }
  });
}


function callCreateData() {
  return new Promise(async (resolve) => {
    console.log('    ======before creating data');
    await createData().then((dataReturn) => {
      console.log('        ----datareturn length=%s', dataReturn.length);
    });
    console.log('    ======after creating data');
  });
}

function callingMom() {
  return askMom().then((str) => {
    console.log(str);
  });
}

callingMom().then(callCreateData);
```